# angular input type datetime-local

Tags: angular, html

I am using angular 7 and i would like to have an input type with dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss
Currently i'm using  datetime-local and it's only limited to dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm.
For my search i also would like to use ss(seconde). How can i do it?
what is the appropriate value for input to have the seconds.
Here is my code

```
<div class="form-inline col-sm-7">
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date1"  [(ngModel)]="dateBefore"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date2" [(ngModel)]="dateAfter"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mb-2" (click)="searchAuditDate()">Chercher</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use seconds in datetime-local you will have to add [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#step) attribute to it.

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date1"  [(ngModel)]="dateBefore" step="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding step attribute will resolve your issue.

```
<input type=datetime-local value="2013-10-24T20:36:00" step="1">
```